# Cancel button doesn't close login popup in W8 Facebook C# SDK 6.1.2

Tags: windows-8, facebook-c#-sdk, windows-store-apps, facebook-login, cancel-button

I'm developing a Windows Store App using Facebook C# SDK 6.1.2 (https://github.com/facebook-csharp-sdk/facebook-windows8-sample).

But, I have a problem: after opened login popup, if user click on Cancel Button nothing happened.

I think that the login popup must be closed.

Is there a way to handle the cancel button event click? Or this is a sdk issue?

Answer (score 0):

the cancel button is in the facebook page itself , and you can't handle it inside this frame , but if the user want to cancel the operation he can press `ESC` button , or click on the back arrow on the left top of this frame that next to **connecting to a service**.

Comment: So this is a bug? Because the button don't have any action.

Comment: Issue fixed by Facebook team.